# Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4044

Tags: plugins, wp-query, core

I've made a custom plugin, but somehow I've made something that fills up my `debug.log` with garbage. It looks a bit like something this is faulty in the WordPress-core, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Here is an extract of one of the 3 errors, that get's repeated 5 times per page request:**

```txt
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4044
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /index.php:0
PHP   2. require() /index.php:4
PHP   3. wp() /wp/wp-blog-header.php:16
PHP   4. WP->main() /wp/wp-includes/functions.php:1291
PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:750
PHP   6. apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:379
PHP   7. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:189
PHP   8. My\Custom\Class->some_method() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
PHP   9. WP_Query->is_front_page() /wp-content/plugins/my-custom-made-plugin/my-custom-made-plugin.php:115
PHP  10. WP_Query->is_page() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3954
```

### How I read the error-log statement

To sum up the error, this is how I read the error-log:

--

**Trace#7: WP_Hook->apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:189**

I register `My\Custom\Class` (from my Plugin) on the filter: `request`, like this:

```
add_filter( 'request', [ $this, 'some_method' ], 1, 1 );
```

--

**Trace#8: My\Custom\Class->some_method() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303**

`My\Custom\Class->some_method()` calls `is_front_page()`, like this:

```php
public function some_method( $query ) {
  $my_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $my_query->parse_query( $query );
  
  if ( $my_query->is_admin() || $my_query->is_home() || $my_query->is_front_page() ) {
    return $query;
  }
  ...
  ...
```

--

**Trace#9: WP_Query->is_front_page() /wp-content/plugins/my-custom-made-plugin/my-custom-made-plugin.php:115**

From there, the `is_front_page()` is called:

WordPress Core function: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8.3/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3954

--

**Trace#10 WP_Query->is_page() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3954**

Which calls `is_page()`:

WordPress Core function: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8.3/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L4044

--

**Which throws the PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4044**

Since I assume there is no `ID` on `$page_obj`.

## BUT WHY?!

Does WordPress Core lack a check, if there is an `ID` on that `$page_obj` or am I using the function incorrectly?

---

### Full Debug.log extract

This is what I get in the `debug.log`-file. And these below-written lines are written 5 times *per page load*, which is approximately 180 lines added to the `debug.log`, for every page that is loaded.

```txt
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4044
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /index.php:0
PHP   2. require() /index.php:4
PHP   3. wp() /wp/wp-blog-header.php:16
PHP   4. WP->main() /wp/wp-includes/functions.php:1291
PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:750
PHP   6. apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:379
PHP   7. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:189
PHP   8. My\Custom\Class->some_method() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
PHP   9. WP_Query->is_front_page() /wp-content/plugins/my-custom-made-plugin/my-custom-made-plugin.php:115
PHP  10. WP_Query->is_page() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3954
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4046
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /index.php:0
PHP   2. require() /index.php:4
PHP   3. wp() /wp/wp-blog-header.php:16
PHP   4. WP->main() /wp/wp-includes/functions.php:1291
PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:750
PHP   6. apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:379
PHP   7. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:189
PHP   8. My\Custom\Class->some_method() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
PHP   9. WP_Query->is_front_page() /wp-content/plugins/my-custom-made-plugin/my-custom-made-plugin.php:115
PHP  10. WP_Query->is_page() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3954
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_name' of non-object in /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4048
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /index.php:0
PHP   2. require() /index.php:4
PHP   3. wp() /wp/wp-blog-header.php:16
PHP   4. WP->main() /wp/wp-includes/functions.php:1291
PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:750
PHP   6. apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:379
PHP   7. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:189
PHP   8. My\Custom\Class->some_method() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
PHP   9. WP_Query->is_front_page() /wp-content/plugins/my-custom-made-plugin/my-custom-made-plugin.php:115
PHP  10. WP_Query->is_page() /wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3954
```

---

### Ideas and info

**Dumping `my_query`**

If I add a dump before calling `is_front_page()`, then I can see that the method is available on that query:

```php
public function some_method( $query ) {
  $my_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $my_query->parse_query( $query );
  
  vardump( $my_query ); // HERE! is_front_page() is available. 
  if ( $my_query->is_admin() || $my_query->is_home() || $my_query->is_front_page() ) {
    return $query;
  }
  ...
  ...
```

### System info

- WordPress version `5.8.3`

Comment: What is the purpose of `some_method`? What does it do? I’m wager there’s nothing wrong with core. You’re filtering `request` and if you’re doing something unsupported it’s going to break stuff.

Comment: I omitted that, since I don't find it relevant for the question, which is already stretching a bit wide. And I don't want it to get too 'muddy'. But `some_method` modifies and adds to the `WP_query`, for later use in the code.

Comment: Well, it appears to be relevant. The problem appears to be that your WP_Query thinks `is_page` is `true`, yet that page doesn’t exist. This should not be possible under normal circumstances. Do you have other code filtering queries in any way? Perhaps to force is_page to be true?

Comment: `add_filter( 'request', [ $this, 'some_method()' ], 1, 1 );` is certainly invalid. Tried `add_filter( 'request', [ $this, 'some_method' ], 1, 1 );`?

Comment: @fuxia - That was a typo in the question (it's already written as you suggest in the code. I've corrected the question.

Comment: I'd say that `WP_Query::is_page()` should have checked whether [`$page_obj`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8.3/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L4040) is an object because the [`get_queried_object()` method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8.3/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3477) can return null if there is no queried object... But you could also ensure there's a queried object by doing `$my_query->query( $query )` instead of `$my_query->parse_query( $query )`.. or just wait until hook like `wp` runs to call those `is_` functions..